# How to implement common validation using OOP?

Tags: php, oop

I use Strategy pattern, that implies using interface and some classes, that realize it. After I use Factory pattern, that creates an instance with interface type.

Each classes have method `validate()`. It is something like as:

```
public function validate($file)
    {
        $allowedFileTypes = config('app.allowedFileTypes');
        $maxFileSize = config('app.maxFileSize');

            $validator = Validator::make(
                array('file' => $file),
                array('file' => array(
                    'required',
                    'mimes:' . $allowedFileTypes . '|max:' . $maxFileSize)));

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                //
            }

        }
    }
```

This is method was describe in interface and this method is placed in each classes with minor changes. So I try to use `DRY principle` and take off validation code of the classes. But I dont know in which form to do that:

- As abstract validation class?
- As Service for injection
- Or class, that can be inherit

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) is a relevant project worth checking out.

Comment: Problem is not in how to write validation, problem is in OOP and SOLID architecture

Comment: I'm aware, hence it being only "relevant". There's probably a wealth of knowledge more specific to what you're asking behind the project as well.

Comment: May be use Abstract Factory instead Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's many ways to do this, and there's not a single right answer. If there's just a single instance of this function though, and it doesn't need to reference `$this`, then I think the most correct answer is to just create a standalone function outside a class.

It looks like you're doing something similar with `config`, although I think that function is a bit problematic as it clearly seems to use global/singleton state.

Comment: And use this as service? I dont want to write the same validation class for each classes. Can you extend your opinion?

Comment: May be use Abstract Factory instead Factory?

Comment: Please read my answer again, I suggested to *not* use any classes for this. So no validation classes, no abstract factories, no factories.